# ggmap geocode query to google api

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

When querying for lon/lat to google api, even for a single location, I get a warning `**geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**` api returns NA. I am way under the daily limit of 2500 - not exactly sure why I get the warrning. Here is an example:

```
geocode("Paris")
 Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris&key=xxx
      lon lat
    1  NA  NA
    Warning message:
    geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Paris"
```

Using devetool version of ggmap and have the api_key registered with google.

```
Versions: ggmap_2.7.904, R version 3.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The issue was resolved after:

1. In addition to registering the API_KEY, one needs to also add credit card information with Google Cloud Platform to complete the registration. [This link was helpful][1].
2. Once that is entered, the api query worked.
3. The devtool version of ggmap need to be installed and R needed to be restarted.